# How can I force an Outlook folder to display (by default) the "To" column instead of the "From" column when creating the folder via Microsoft Graph?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have code that programmatically creates a bunch of emails using Graph.  These emails are created in a subfolder under the Drafts folder.  However, the subfolder always displays the drafts using the default 'From' column first, instead of the 'To' column (which you might expect if you create a child folder under Drafts or Sent Items).

[image: Image of programmatically generated draft emails]

I checked the [Microsoft Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and there does not seem to be a way to set the default column order for an Outlook folder.  Is it possible?

I then used classic desktop Outlook (in Windows) to change the View Settings to include the "To" column and removed the "From" folder and that worked - but only in that client.  The changes are not reflected in Outlook on the Web.  Is there a way to force the View Settings onto the web client?